# Qt example of using offscreen rendering

Tags: c++, qt, rendering, blit

I am trying to use offscreen rendering in my Qt 5.5 application.  I'm looking at an example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinthread-threadrenderer-cpp.html

One of the classes is derived from "QSGSimpleTextureNode", but when I try to include the header:

```
    #include <QSGSimpleTextureNode>
```

I get an error "No such file or directory", in the example it includes:

```
    include <qsgsimpletexturenode.h>
```

Not sure why, however what I'm trying to do is use offscreen rendering to prepare a complete bitmap ready to blit to the visible context, is there a good simple and complete example of how to do this?

Edit...bit more information, I'm trying to create a QWidget derived class that shows a compass strip, the strip will typically show the current compass heading in the centre of the strip with a specific number of ticks either side of the centre showing periodic angle positions.  The full strip will be rendered in the offscreen bit map and only the part that matches the displayable screen area for the current heading will be copied to the visible area.

Project file:

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
    #
    # Project created by QtCreator 2016-03-07T08:45:43
    #
    #-------------------------------------------------

    QT       += core gui

    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = QtFCS
    TEMPLATE = app


    SOURCES += main.cpp\
        clsMainWin.cpp \
        clsPSstrip.cpp \
        clsSimWin.cpp

    HEADERS  += \
        clsMainWin.h \
        clsPSstrip.h \
        clsSimWin.h

    FORMS    += \
        clsMainWin.ui \
        clsSimWin.ui
```

Comment: Just as a basic check, you've got `quick` in your `.pro` right?

Comment: in the `QT` line add `quick` after `core gui`.

Comment: thank you, now I can add the header.

Comment: A `.pro` file is used to generate the `Makefile`, by adding that you're telling `qmake` you want to include the `quick` libraries and headers.

Comment: I'll move it to the answer from the comments then, for the next person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add `quick` to the `.pro` file so that `qmake` knows to include the `quick` related headers and libraries.